# testing react-scroll - "Seems containerElement is not an ancestor of the Element"

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-scroll

I am working on a browser based react app, and have a problem that occurs in test code but not in the browser.

I have a requirement to scroll to an element within a scrollable div. The project I'm working on already uses react-scroll, and implementing the requirement seemed straightforward, and all works as expected in the browser.

However, when testing the component, if I carry out any action that prompts scrolling behaviour the test fails with `Seems containerElement is not an ancestor of the Element`

A simple minimum reducible example is

```
import {Element, scroller} from 'react-scroll';
import {useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Scroll() {

    const scrollToBottomElement = () => {
        scroller.scrollTo('atTheBottom', {
            containerId: 'containerElement',
            smooth: true,
            duration: 300,
        });
    };

    useEffect(scrollToBottomElement, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Element
                name="container"
                id="containerElement"
                style={{
                    position: 'relative',
                    height: '100px',
                    overflow: 'scroll',
                    marginBottom: '100px',
                }}
            >
                <Element
                    name="atTheTop"
                    style={{
                        marginBottom: '300px',
                    }}
                >
                    top
                </Element>
                <Element
                    name="atTheBottom"
                >
                    bottom
                </Element>
            </Element>
        </div>
    );
}
```

with a failing test:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Scroll from "./Scroll";
describe('Scroll', () => {
    it('should render scroll without error', async () => {
        render(<Scroll />);
    });
});
```

The problem occurs when the `react-scroll` library attempts to add up offsets between the scroll target and any interim elements up to the container. When we get to [this line](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/blob/236ddf05512bfd0c654f663381328ff3a8d00135/modules/mixins/utils.js#L27), element is the scroll target, and the value of its `offsetParent` is `null` (debugging in the browser on the other hand shows that the offsetParent is populated as expected).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent), there are just 3 conditions that cause `offsetParent` to be null. I guess that the DOM tree as implemented by the render function in `@testing-library/react` is different to that implemented by the browser, but assuming that it complies with the contract of `HTMLElement` I'm not sure which of the 3 conditions might be causing the null `offsetParent`.

I'm pretty new to React and Javascript, after a long time as a Java/Kotlin engineer, so I'm hoping I'm just making a silly mistake somewhere.

Below is a relevant screenshot of a debug session, with a breakpoint in the react-scroll code.

[image: Debug session showing null offsetParent]